# Is there any option to migrate only orders from magento1 to magento2?

Tags: magento2, data-migration

My scenario is :
I have migrated all data from Magento1 to Magento2 using live DB backup. So I could not use delta migration for the incremental changes. But I need to migrate the newly created orders from magento1 live to my existing magento2 migrated site. Can you please suggest an option for this?

Answer (score 1):

Try to import all data using [Magento Data Migration Tool](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/bk-migration-guide.html) to another DB and work with it since then.